# 2013 Breadcrumb is reset in use

Tags: sharepoint-designer, navigation, migration

Getting a conversion to 2013 from 2007.

I have Breadcrumbs visible and they they seem to work going down chain.

```
TOP
|- First SubSite
|-- Second layer Site   I can see this properly.
```

I Click on First Sub Site and then click on breadcrumb but it shows This page location is:_______________

I was expecting to keep top site in view.

This was the change in masterpage I did:

```
<div class="ms-breadcrumb-dropdownBox" >  <!-- style="display:none;" -->
<SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaBreadcrumbDropdown" runat="server">
    <SharePoint:PopoutMenu
        Visible="true"
        runat="server"
```

What more do I need to change to not reset the breacdcrumb box when I execute it?

Comment: Have you check all your subsites have same Master page and navigation settings as main site?

Comment: Yes from Top Site, Site Settings, Master Page, I then check the box for Reset all subsites to inherit this system master page setting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to change how the breadcrumb work. Here is a brief description on how the breadcrumb render and hope it helps:

ref: [Navigation Controls](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ms476607(v=office.14).aspx)

Your Master page should contains similiar snippet:

```
<asp:contentplaceholder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigation" runat="server">
<SharePoint:PopoutMenu
    runat="server"
    ID="GlobalBreadCrumbNavPopout"
    IconUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
    IconAlt="Navigate Up"
    IconOffsetX=0
    IconOffsetY=112
    IconWidth=16
    IconHeight=16
    AnchorCss="s4-breadcrumb-anchor"
    AnchorOpenCss="s4-breadcrumb-anchor-open"
    MenuCss="s4-breadcrumb-menu">
    <div class="s4-breadcrumb-top">
        <asp:Label 
            runat="server" 
            CssClass="s4-breadcrumb-header" 
            Text="This page location is:" />
    </div>
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:ListSiteMapPath
            runat="server"
            SiteMapProviders="SPSiteMapProvider,SPContentMapProvider"
            RenderCurrentNodeAsLink="false"
            PathSeparator=""
            CssClass="s4-breadcrumb"
            NodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbNode"
            CurrentNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbCurrentNode"
            RootNodeStyle-CssClass="s4-breadcrumbRootNode"
            NodeImageOffsetX=0
            NodeImageOffsetY=353
            NodeImageWidth=16
            NodeImageHeight=16
            NodeImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
            RTLNodeImageOffsetX=0
            RTLNodeImageOffsetY=376
            RTLNodeImageWidth=16
            RTLNodeImageHeight=16
            RTLNodeImageUrl="/_layouts/images/fgimg.png"
            HideInteriorRootNodes="true"
            SkipLinkText="" />
        </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</SharePoint:PopoutMenu>
<div class="s4-die">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder id="PlaceHolderGlobalNavigationSiteMap" runat="server" Visible="false">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
```

The breadcrumb menu is rendered by a PopoutMenu control. This control contains a Label control for the menu header and a **ListSiteMapPath** control for the hyperlinks that enable users to navigate the website. The **ListSiteMapPath** control is nested within another ContentPlaceholder control (ID="PlaceHolderTitleBreadcrumb"), so that it can also **be overridden in a content page**.

In my test, I can override the breadcrumb by modify the Page Layout of subsites. So you may compare the different between main site and sub sites for:

1. Page layouts
2. Master page
3. Navigation settings